# How can I fix this "multi-part Identifier could not be bound"?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables. They are:

```
Country(CountryID,CountryName,AboutCountry)
City(CityID,CityName,Location,AboutCity,CountryID)
```

They are in One-to-many relationship(From Country's perspective). I created a view like this

```
CREATE VIEW GetByID AS 
SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM 
City  INNER JOIN Country ON
City.CountryID = Country.CountryID
```

I am getting this error called multi-part identifier could not be bound after executing this query

```
SELECT * FROM GetByID WHERE City.CityID = 1
```

I used **1** because I know **CityID = 1** belongs a city from the city table. If I execute without using the view then I don't get that error anymore. Why this error is happening? Could someone please explain this error and how can I avoid this kind of error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The view GetByID has one single column, CountryName. You can't access the City tables columns via the view.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my concept. I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a view with only `CountryName` as field. And then you are searching for `CityID` which isn't in your view. It seems you are approaching your view as a procedure. You should treat it as a table, it's created with fields, and you can't query whats not already there. You should expand your view to include `CityID`.